# Validations.pattern doesn't work with Regex

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I have reactive form and one of the controls should be validated with the pattern `.*[^\s].*`. In case it is used in template-driven forms, it works well. But in a case of reactive - does not. What should I change to fix it?

```
this._form = this._formBuilder.group({
  description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*[^\S].*')]]
}
```

Comment: Use `'.*\\s.*'` or `/\s/`

Comment: Well, looks like you need `'.*\\s.*'`. Passing a RegExp still requires a full string match, so the `/\S*\s.*/` should work, too.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`Validator.js`](https://github.com/btrigueiro/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/validators.ts#L94):

```
/**
* Validator that requires a control to match a regex to its value.
*/
static pattern(pattern: string|RegExp): ValidatorFn {
    if (!pattern) return Validators.nullValidator;
    let regex: RegExp;
    let regexStr: string;
    if (typeof pattern === 'string') {
      regexStr = `^${pattern}$`;
      regex = new RegExp(regexStr);
    } else {
      regexStr = pattern.toString();
      regex = pattern;
    }
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      if (isEmptyInputValue(control.value)) {
        return null;  // don't validate empty values to allow optional controls
      }
      const value: string = control.value;
      return regex.test(value) ? null :
                                 {'pattern': {'requiredPattern': regexStr, 'actualValue': value}};
    };
  }
```

The point is that the regex pattern is passed either like a regex literal, or as a string literal. When you pass it as  a regex literal, you may use

```
/\S*\s.*/
```

It will be "converted" to a string with `pattern.toString()` and `^` and `$` will be added - `"^\\S*\\s.*$"`. This is exactly a string pattern you may pass in the `Validators.Pattern`, too.

Note that `^\S*\s.*$`  will match a string that starts with 0+ non-whitespace chars, then has 1 obligatory whitespace, and then has any 0+ chars other than line break chars. It is a bit faster than `/^.*\s.*$/`.  Note that `\s` = `[^\S]`.